# Selenium - Python How to click row element one by one inside <table><tr> loop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to query html table.
**below is my code,**

```
browser.get("url.html")

# Wait 20 seconds for page to load
# have EC.visibility_of_element_located here

table_rows = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='table_id']/tbody/tr")
for row in table_rows:
    print(row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[2]').text)
    table_link = row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[1]/a')
    table_link.click()
```

**Error:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException:
```

I believe i am lost in the page context. How to get this functionality working.

1. i mean go to one page.
2. for each table tr
3. read td
4. click 1st td
5. scrape some information from (4) th page
6. go back
7. again loop continues

Answer (score 0):

`selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException:` come when element is not attached with page.When click on the link the page is getting refreshed and element no longer attached to the page and it become `stale`.

To overcome this you need to re-assigned the element.
Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_all_elements_located`()

```
table_rows = WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='table_id']/tbody/tr")))
for row in range(len(table_rows)):
    # re-assigned variable here
    table_rows = WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='table_id']/tbody/tr")))
    print(table_rows[row].find_element_by_xpath('./td[2]').text)
    table_link = table_rows[row].find_element_by_xpath('./td[1]/a')
    table_link.click()
    #Perform details for the page
    #
    browser.back()
```

You need to import below libarries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```